# getting uncommon rows of 2 tab separated files based on one column using AWK

Tags: awk

I have 2 tab separated file like these 2 examples:

`file1`:

```
chr10   103912167   103917248   NOLC1   ENST00000603742.1
chr16   18573197    18558622    NOMO2   ENST00000543392.1
chr1    120611947   120572610   NOTCH2  ENST00000256646.2
```

`file2`:

```
chr16   18573197    18558622    NOMO2   ENST00000543392.1
chr1    120611947   120572610   NOTCH2  ENST00000256646.2
chr1    145209308   145248834   NOTCH2NL    ENST00000344859.3
```

based on the `4th` column, I want to isolate the rows in the first file that are not present in the 2nd file. here is the expected output:

`expected output`:

```
chr10   103912167   103917248   NOLC1   ENST00000603742.1
```

I am doing that in `AWK` using the following command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4]!=$4;next}a[$4]' file1 file2 > results.txt
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=1;next}!a[$4]' file2 file1
#=> chr10   103912167   103917248   NOLC1   ENST00000603742.1
```

Since you want output content from file1 based on file2, you should read file2 first.

Note if file2 could be empty, you should change to different file checking methods, like `ARGIND==1` for GNU awk, or `FILENAME=="file2"` etc.